# How to extract elements that include $ sign from a character vector

Tags: r

Suppose that R output is as the following:

```
 > website.fund.chvec1

  [1] ""         "LOGIN"          "or"             "SIGN"           "UP "          
      ""         "The"            "Team:"          ""              
 [10] "$74,810"  "TOTAL"          "RAISED"         "SO"             "$14,530"
```

I want to extract every element that includes `$` sign from the character vector `website.fund.chvec1`. Is there anyway to do it? I mean, besides `website.fund.chvec1`, I also have `website.fund.chvec2`, `website.fund.chvec3`, etc, and the index of elements including the `$` sign is not always 10 and 14....

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, easy:

```
grep('\\$', website.fund.chvec)
```

`grep` searches for a regular expression, so I need to escape the `$` sign which is a special character in regular expressions. Alternatively, you could use

```
grep('$', website.fund.chvec, fixed = TRUE)
```

to make `grep` treat the search pattern as-is.

Comment: If you want to get the elements instead of the indices, you can add `value=TRUE`.

Comment: thank you :) I tried grep('$', website.fund.chvec) but the result was not what I wanted so I asked here....now I know that I was supposed to write '\\$' instead of '$'....what does "\\" exactly do?

Comment: @user2871333 "$" is a special character in regular expressions (used to denote the end of a string). So you have to escape it with a "\". But R treats "\" in a string as special, so you escape that with another "\", and you get "\\$". The `fixed` argument you see in the second example here tells `grep` to *not* use regular expressions, in which case the "$" is not longer special, so no longer needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

```
require(stringr)
website.fund.chvec[str_detect(website.fund.chvec, pattern = "\\$")]
```